# Django fails on attempt to create a custom login form

Tags: python, django

I try to create a custom login form, so I have added a `LoginForm` class in `forms.py`:

```
from django.forms import forms, CharField, BooleanField, TextInput, PasswordInput


class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    email = CharField(label='email', max_length=255, widget=TextInput("E-mail"))
    password = CharField(label='password', max_length=255, widget=PasswordInput("Password"))
    remember = BooleanField(label='remember', required=False)
```

But it throws on the form loading:

```
File "/home/ghostman/Projects/asknow/asknow/asknow/urls.py", line 22, in <module>
    url(r'^', include('app.urls')),
  File "/home/ghostman/Projects/asknow/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/home/ghostman/Projects/asknow/env/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/ghostman/Projects/asknow/asknow/app/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from app import views
  File "/home/ghostman/Projects/asknow/asknow/app/views.py", line 6, in <module>
    from app.forms import LoginForm
  File "/home/ghostman/Projects/asknow/asknow/app/forms.py", line 4, in <module>
    class LoginForm(forms.Form):
  File "/home/ghostman/Projects/asknow/asknow/app/forms.py", line 5, in LoginForm
    email = CharField(label='email', max_length=255, widget=TextInput("E-mail"))
  File "/home/ghostman/Projects/asknow/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py", line 284, in __init__
    attrs = attrs.copy()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

Seems it is inside Django... What's wrong? How to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The widgets `TextInput()` and `PasswordInput()` dont take any positional arguments.
Try:

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    email = CharField(label='email', max_length=255, widget=TextInput())
    password = CharField(label='password', max_length=255, widget=PasswordInput())
    remember = BooleanField(label='remember', required=False)
```

Also for emails, you can use an `EmailField` and an `EmailInput` widget.

Comment: I did using a tutorial, seems it's wrong... Thank you for the answer!

Comment: They might have had something like `TextInput(attrs={'size': 10, 'title': 'Your name'})`, the Keyword arg `attrs` can be passed but it is a dict, example here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget